# Bootstrap 4.00 grid System not working in UC Browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, uc-browser

I am new in Bootstrap and developed a web page using bootstrap,My page works fine pc/laptop browsers but when i use uc browser my grid layout does not work .is there any way to fix this?
heres my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MD</title>
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700"
rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <section class="itsolutions" id="it">
  <h2>IT Solutions</h2>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <i class="ion-settings icon-big ic"></i>
    <h3>Website Design & Development</h3>
    <p>texts</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <i class="ion-android-bulb icon-big ic"></i>
    <h3>Software Solutions</h3>
    <p>texts</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, Bootstrap supports the latest versions of each major platform's default browsers. Note that proxy browsers (such as Opera Mini, Opera Mobile's Turbo mode, **UC Browser**, Amazon Silk) are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You welcome to Bootstrap. You just need change some part of your html code to use bootstrap classes for ***extra-small(xs)*** scales.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <!--Here is changed-->
        <i class="ion-settings icon-big ic"></i>
        <h3>Website Design & Development</h3>
        <p>texts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <!--Here is changed-->
        <i class="ion-android-bulb icon-big ic"></i>
        <h3>Software Solutions</h3>
        <p>texts</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp) may help you to know which class related to which screen width in pixel.